# Android app doesn't save in mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

I have reservation activity which allow users to reserving table. The problem is that doesn't save anything into database which is mysql. Doesn't show anything in LogCat and there is no errors at all. Just reload the same activity. The flow of activities is

```
Activity_1 -> Activity_2 -> Activity_3 -> Activity_4 -> Activity_5 (last and finish)
```

I've passed what data I need with intents between activities.

Activity_2

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(Activity_2.this, Activity_3.class); 
    newActivity.putExtra("Position", Position); 
    newActivity.putExtra("resultServer", resultServer); 
    newActivity.putExtra("id", MyArrList.get(position).get("id").toString());
    startActivity(newActivity);
```

Activity_3

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
    table_id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
btnMenues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_3.this, Activity_4.class);
                String Name = editText1.getText().toString();
                String Email = editText2.getText().toString();
                String Phone = editText3.getText().toString();
                String Comment = editText4.getText().toString();
                String DateTime = datePicker.getText().toString();
                String numberOfPeople = editText5.getText().toString();

                intent.putExtra("Name", Name);
                intent.putExtra("Email", Email);
                intent.putExtra("Phone", Phone);
                intent.putExtra("Comment", Comment);
                intent.putExtra("DateTime", DateTime);
                intent.putExtra("numberOfPeople", numberOfPeople);
                intent.putExtra("table_id", table_id);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        //}
    }); 

}
```

Activity_4

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        getName = extras.getString("Name");
        getEmail = extras.getString("Email");
        getPhone = extras.getString("Phone");
        getComment = extras.getString("Comment");
        getDateTime = extras.getString("DateTime");
        getnumberOfPeople = extras.getString("numberOfPeople");
        table_id = extras.getString("table_id");
    }
 Intent newActivity = new Intent(Activity_4.this, Activity_5.class);
    newActivity.putExtra("Position", Position);
    newActivity.putExtra("resultServer", resultServer);
    newActivity.putExtra("table_id", MyArrList.get(position).get("table_id").toString());

            startActivity(newActivity);
```

Activity_5

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.table_information);

    Intent intent= getIntent();
    curPosition = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("Position")); 
    resultServer = String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("resultServer")); 

    try {
        MyArrList = ConvertJSONtoArrayList(resultServer);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("ArrayList Size",String.valueOf(MyArrList.size()));

    // Show Image Full
    new DownloadFullPhotoFileAsync().execute();

    btnFinish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);

    btnFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                getName = extras.getString("Name");
                getEmail = extras.getString("Email");
                getPhone = extras.getString("Phone");
                getComment = extras.getString("Comment");
                getDateTime = extras.getString("DateTime");
                getnumberOfPeople = extras.getString("numberOfPeople");
                getTable = extras.getString("table_id");
        }

            new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);

            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });

}
class SummaryAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private void postData(String getNameToData, String getEmailData, String getPhoneData,
            String getCommentData, String getDateTimeData, String getnumberOfPeopleData, String getTable) {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://link.to.site/save.php");

        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", getNameToData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", getEmailData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Phone", getPhoneData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Comment", getCommentData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", getDateTimeData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numberOfPeople", getnumberOfPeopleData));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("table_id", getTable));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

I've missed somewhere something but can't figured out what exactly.

Update with `save.php`

```
$icon = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
if(!$icon)
{ 
   die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_erroe());
}
mysql_select_db("database", $icon)or die("database selection error");
echo json_encode($data);

$Name=$_POST['Name'];
$Phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$Email=$_POST['Email'];
$Comment=$_POST['Comment'];
$DateTime=$_POST['DateTime'];
$numberOfPeople=$_POST['numberOfPeople'];
    $DateTime= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($DateTime));
    $table_id = $_POST['table_id'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO reservation (Name, Phone, Email, Comment, DateTime, numberOfPeople, table)
         VALUES ('$Name', '$Phone', '$Email', '$Comment', '$DateTime', '$numberOfPeople', '$table_id')",$icon);

mysql_close($icon);
```

UPDATED with `logcat` After `Activity_3` it's lost intents.

```
11-30 03:40:59.497: D/Activity_3(1642): testName test@test.com 123456 testComment 30-11-2014 3:40 2 1
11-30 03:41:01.817: D/Activity_4(1642): null null null null null null 1
11-30 03:41:04.667: D/Actiovity_5(1642): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b2f5c9a0
```

On `Activity_4` it hold only `table_id`

Comment: Can you post the code for `save.php`? Is there anything in the server error log?

Comment: I've posted `save.php`. And no, there is nothing on the host. Nothing for errors.. Just reload same screen `(Activity_5)` on every click of `Finish` button and nothing is saved in DB

Comment: you dont check for error enough, and no logging, this is not going to help you. and you made a typo at `mysql_erroe`, not to mention mysql extension is deprecated

Comment: Agree but I'm not sure that the error is in `.php` file. Also I'm aware about `mysql_*` deprecation.

Comment: @Goro you have many issues see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not complete you have only coded the happy case.

You are missing the following:

- `echo json_encode($data);` data is undefined
- POST value server side check (use isset())
- upgrade to `mysqli_` or at least use `mysql_real_escape()`
- `BasicNameValuePair("Date", getDateTimeData)` and `$DateTime=$_POST['DateTime'];` won't match
- check if the query executed properly
- check if a row has been inserted
- add error reporting in PHP
- use logging (for ex: `error_log()`) or use network tools to watch the request
- log the response back in java using `LogCat`

---

```
if(isset($_POST['Name'], $_POST['Phone'], $_POST['Email'], $_POST['Comment'], 
        $_POST['numberOfPeople'], $_POST['DateTime'])){

    $icon = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass", "database");
    if(!$icon)
    { 
       die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $name=$_POST['Name'];
    $phone=$_POST['Phone'];
    $email=$_POST['Email'];
    $comment=$_POST['Comment'];
    $number_of_people=$_POST['numberOfPeople'];
    $date_time= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['DateTime']));
    $table_id = $_POST['table_id'];



    $query = sprintf("
             INSERT INTO reservation 
             (`Name`, `Phone`, `Email`, `Comment`, 
              `DateTime`, `numberOfPeople`, `table`)
             VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                mysql_real_escape_string($name),
                mysql_real_escape_string($phone),                       
                mysql_real_escape_string($email)),
                mysql_real_escape_string($comment),
                mysql_real_escape_string($date_time),
                mysql_real_escape_string($number_of_people),
                mysql_real_escape_string($table_id);


    $result = mysql_query($query,$icon);

    if(!$result)
    {
        die('Could not execute : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "Success !";
    }else{
        echo "Fail !";
    }

    mysql_close($icon);
}else{
    echo "missing values";
}
```

**edit:**

Don't forget to log the response in android:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
Log.d(LOG_TAG, response.toString());
```

**edit again**
If you get null values in `activity4` it means the editText are null in `Activity3`, make sure they are initialized in `onCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText1 =  (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 =  (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 =  (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.editText3);
    ......
}
```

then on your button event do this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_3.this, Activity_4.class);
        intent.putExtra("Name", editText1.getText());
        intent.putExtra("Email", editText2.getText());
        intent.putExtra("Phone", editText3.getText());
        intent.putExtra("Comment", editText4.getText());
        intent.putExtra("DateTime", datePicker.getText());
        intent.putExtra("numberOfPeople", editText5.getText());
        intent.putExtra("table_id", getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I will try to fix all of this but want first to make it work. Without `table_id` and all about table is working properly and saving data in database. So I'm guessing is something with intents and passing this `table_id`.

Comment: When I put `table_id` in the query `("INSERT INTO reservation (Name, Phone, Email, Comment, DateTime, numberOfPeople, table)
         VALUES ('$Name', '$Phone', '$Email', '$Comment', '$DateTime', '$numberOfPeople', '$table_id')"` it doesn't insert anything in database. But when I remove it is save everything.. except table_id in this field is 0 of course.

Comment: @Goro see my update and, im gonna check your code for table_id, I didnt notice an issue with it

Comment: There is no errors when I try from app again. Just reload the screen and nothing saved in database.

Comment: In logcat I just see `11-29 18:11:10.855: D/curPosition(1758): 2
11-29 18:11:10.855: D/MyArrList.size(1758): 3` which is normal .. `curPosition` is correct and `MyArrList:3` is also correct

Comment: This is what I see in logcat - `11-30 03:33:27.440: D/err(1004): org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@b2f77b08
`

Comment: Please see my edit on question. It loose intents after third Activity. I can't see why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65902/discussion-between-meda-and-goro).

Comment: Since the question was that doesn't want to save into database I will close this one and accept your answer because now is saving in database. Not what must save but at least is saving for now.